# How can I export my repo from gitlab 8.7.5?

Tags: gitlab

I installed a new GitLab server and want to export my repo from GitLab 8.7.5 to the new server.

I can't found "Export project" in GitLab 8.7.5. How to export a complete repo and in this case (source code, commits history, wiki, ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like that version has no export feature. Please take a look at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/import_export.html for more info.

Comment: So no luck to migrate the commits, branches history and wiki ?

Comment: You could do it after upgrading to any version that supports import/export.